# jPOS taskadaptor get object instance

Tags: jpos

i would like to ask a little question about task adaptor in q2.

i have a class that extends TaskAdaptor and an xml class with  to instantiate it.

so my question is, how do i get the object instance created by the xml in java?

Thank you very much for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

You use the NameRegistrar to get a reference to your object, but please keep in mind that the `TaskAdaptor` was created in the early Q2 days in order to reuse Tasks created to run under QSP (QSP was the original version, Q2 stands for 'QSP version 2').

I don't think we have any of those old tasks in the jPOS system now, so I wonder why you need the TaskAdaptor; if you have Tasks of your own, it might be easier to upgrade them to full QBeans (just by extending QBeanSupport or implementing the simple QBean interface).

Please take a look at http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf, there's a chapter about writing your own jPOS Services (aka *QBeans*).